# If find a date, then do...- VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, find

I struggle with one simple code that does not cooperate with me ;)
I have in the column `L` some dates beginning from the row `5`. The dates are in format `yyyy.mm`. but in the formula bar is visible the whole date in the format `dd.mm.yyyy`.

In column `F` are the same dates, formatted in the same way. The only difference is that here some cells are merged. Each date is located in a cell that is merged with next 2 cells.
It means in the cell `F5` is a date.
This cell is merged with `F6` and `F7`.
In the cell `F8` is next date. This cell is merged…

I’d like to take first date from the column `L` and find them in the column `F` and if found, do some actions.

The problem is that the variable `Dates` is every time empty. I’d appreciate any advice.

```
Public Sub Fsaldo()

Dim Finanse As Worksheet
Dim x As Range
Dim Dates As Range
Dim Sum As Range
Dim State As Range

Set Finanse = Sheets("Finanse")

For Each x In Finanse.Range("L6:L100")
    If x <= Now() And IsDate(x) Then
        Set Dates = Finanse.Range("F5:F100").Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'       MsgBox Dates.Address
'       MsgBox Data
        Set Sum = Dates.Offset(0, 3)
'       MsgBox sum.Address
        Set State = x.Offset(0, 1)
        State = Sum.Value + Sum.Offset(1, 0).Value + Sum.Offset(2, 0).Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Kind regards
Neke

Comment: You're looking for a date in column F...is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, my mistake. I've corrected  already the above text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As none solved my problem I did it myself...

Once again to make it clear. In both columns I have date written dd.mm.yyyy. The Format of all cells is Custom (yyyy.mm), so that in the cellls are displayed like that 2017.07 but in formula bar is still something like that 01.07.2017.

The above macro did not work because the method find was wrongly used. I changed:

- LookIn:xlFormulas ' instead of looking into cell value I just take the information from formula bar. No idea why xlValues does not work. The values are the same.
- SearchOrder: xlColumns ' this change allows me to find what I search for in merged cells.

Maybe it helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code. You are searching for the range of x. I guess a simple offset wouldn't do the trick because the dates in the column F and L are not in the same order?
your code:

```
Dim x As Range
(...)
For Each x In Finanse.Range("L6:L100")
If x <= Now() And IsDate(x) Then
        Set Dates = Finanse.Range("F5:F100").Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

If a simple offset would work you could try:

```
If x <= Now() And IsDate(x) Then
set Dates = Range(x).offset(0,-6).value
```

if you search for the date, try to add .value at the end.

```
Set Dates = Finanse.Range("F5:F100").Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).value
```

Or instead of searching for the range search for the date. I never searched for a range in Excel vba. I always "read" the value of the cell in a variable an then search for it. But this causes problems if there are duplicates.

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Marco, first of all: thank you for your investigation! With regards to your first question: the dates are in the same order but the offset in between is not constant. In general the trick with offset works, as well as the code when I replace dates by numbers. It does not work with the dates. I do not know why.

Comment: Hi Neke; i did build a simple Excel according to your description.

Comment: I would gess that the bug is in the .find part. My thought was that "Dates" couln't handle the value "finanse.range(F5:F100"......". (normally after .find() I write.activate or .select)  I tried to work around it by first select the range (Range("F5:F100").Select) then find the cell (Selection.Find(What:=x).Activate) an then assign the activecell to Dates (Dates = ActiveCell) But this also didn't work for me. Sorry, I can't find the mistake. But if i have any idea i will let you know. PS: If you are working with dates don't forget, that you can convert values in Dates with "CDate"

Comment: Thanks. I will check your hints Andrzej maybe figure out what is wrong.